# Matlab 'rtifc' error when reading .tif files

Tags: matlab

I seem to be having an issue reading .tif files on Matlab2014a. Whenever I use the imread function to read my image, I get the following output:

```
Error using rtifc
TIFF library error - 'TIFFReadDirectory:  Incorrect count for   "SampleFormat".'

Error in readtif (line 48)
[X, map, details] = rtifc(args);

Error in imread (line 415)
[X, map] = feval(fmt_s.read, filename, extraArgs{:});

Error in circles (line 3)
RGB = imread('C:\users\michael\desktop\inkblob12.tif');
```

I've no idea what the issue is or how to fix it, so any pointers would be greatly appreciated! Many thanks.

EDIT: This is the infinfo output:

```
 Filename: 'C:\users\michael\desktop\inkblob12.tif'
              FileModDate: '10-Mar-2015 14:06:40'
                 FileSize: 159794
                   Format: 'tif'
            FormatVersion: []
                    Width: 250
                   Height: 250
                 BitDepth: 32
                ColorType: 'truecolor'
          FormatSignature: [73 73 42 0]
                ByteOrder: 'little-endian'
           NewSubFileType: 0
            BitsPerSample: [8 8 8 8]
              Compression: 'LZW'
PhotometricInterpretation: 'RGB'
             StripOffsets: [1x21 double]
          SamplesPerPixel: 4
             RowsPerStrip: 12
          StripByteCounts: [1x21 double]
              XResolution: 72.0090
              YResolution: 72.0090
           ResolutionUnit: 'Inch'
                 Colormap: []
      PlanarConfiguration: 'Chunky'
                TileWidth: []
               TileLength: []
              TileOffsets: []
           TileByteCounts: []
              Orientation: 1
                FillOrder: 1
         GrayResponseUnit: 0.0100
           MaxSampleValue: [255 255 255 255]
           MinSampleValue: [0 0 0 0]
             Thresholding: 1
                   Offset: 159126
                 Software: 'Matrox Imaging Library [9.00]                                          ...'
                Predictor: 'Horizontal differencing'
             ExtraSamples: 2
             SampleFormat: {'Unsigned integer'  'Unsigned integer'  'Unsigned integer'}
```

Comment: Could the file you are reading be corrupted / have incorrect format? Have you tried any other TIFF files?

Comment: @scai basically I had some 1000x944 .tif images that were fine to read in matlab, but I opened these images in paint, took 250x250 'blocks' and saved these as new .tif files. I can't open any of those new files, but I don't see why that'd be an issue.

Comment: Neither do I - I just checked by opening a file in paint, saving it out as a .tif, and `imread` on 2013b at least handles it fine. Could you edit the question to show what `imfinfo` returns for one of the problem files?

Comment: @nkjt it's quite annoying because I just made 165 of these new images to test with! Sure, I'll edit it in in about half an hour - I'm just away from my computer at the moment. Thanks!

Comment: @nkjt Image info has been edited in.

Comment: If your MATLAB license permits, submit a help ticket to MathWorks. http://www.mathworks.com/support/contact_us/ This might be a bug in imread.

Comment: @scai I did see that there were some issues with this in the 2012b version (from some Googling) but apparently it was fixed in 2013a. I'll submit a ticket though if no-one can spot anything wrong. Thanks!

Comment: Be sure to attach a copy the problematic TIFF file (assuming no confidential content) so that they can try reproducing your issue.

Comment: @scai That's my issue, unfortunately the images are confidential. But I can try to reproduce my problem with other images.

Comment: Maybe [this](http://www.mathworks.com/support/bugreports/914792) could come helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The specific issue appears to be because the tag for `SampleFormat` is not of a type that the tiff library used can cope with. I suggest you check whether the issue is that this has been changed somehow from your original, working tif to your cropped images.  (You might also want to try just using `imcrop` or something to make the reduced images in MATLAB directly next time around, avoiding potential incompatibility issues entirely).

Since the content of the tags seems to be really just `'Unsigned integer'`, it might work to simply forcibly retag all the images via MATLAB using the gateway to the LibTiff library routines to match what MATLAB expects:

```
t = Tiff('inkblob12.tif','a'); % loop over your file names, if this works
t.setTag('SampleFormat',Tiff.SampleFormat.UInt);
t.close();
```

`a` for append should leave whatever content was already there alone.